# How to fix blue screen when setting a position for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering if someone could help me understand what is going on. I am currently developing a space shooter game, but once I executed a code to change the position all I see on the game tab is a blue screen. I know it is that one line of code because I then commented it out and then it worked just fine when I ran the game.

The line of code is.

```
transform.position = new vector3 (0, 0, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check your camera position?  Please give me your camera position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you attached this script to your camera (And probably other game objects like the sky, rocket and etc are in the `(0, 0, 0)` position). So, when you play the game, the camera moves to `(0, 0, 0)` and nothing shows. Make sure that you set the camera in a position with `z < 0`.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you. This worked. When I was linking the script to player i must have also done the same with the main camera